# Firefox (v58.0 and above) won't load SWF embedded in an html when requested from Windows 10

Tags: facebook, flash, firefox, swfobject

None of our games is playable from Firefox on some computers. Until yesterday, we didn't have the chance to reproduce the error, but now we can on two of our office computers. As a test, this is the link of one of our games which won't load (https://apps.facebook.com/magicquesttcg/)

The only setup where we have been able to reproduce the issue is the following:

**OS**: Windows 10 (64 bits)
**Browser**: Mozilla Firefox v58.0 (https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/58.0/win64/en-US/)
Flash Version installed: v28.0 (latest). We have tried with several flash versions, all of them have the same impact.

When loading the website it will display the "You don't have Flash installed message" (even if it's installed)
We are embedding the swf the simplest way possible, but we have also tried it using swfObject, nothing. It just won't work.
I hope you can help us!

Here's the index.html we are currently using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">  
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
   var v = "\?v=1.5.4.028"
   var platform="fb";
   
   <!-- @return whether the current platform is Facebook or not -->
   function isFacebook(){return platform == "fb";}
        </script>
        
        <!-- Add FACEBOOK Script (Conditionally) -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if(isFacebook())
   {
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   }
  </script>
  
        <title>Magic Quest: TCG</title>
        <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />         
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
            html, body  { height:100%; }
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                   background-color: #000000; }
            object:focus { outline:none; }
            #flashContent { display:none; box-shadow:0px 0px 60px black;}
        </style>
        
        <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens with two hyphens -->
        <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
        <!-- END Browser History required section -->  
            
        <!-- Include support librarys first -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
         var cssStyle = (isFacebook()) ? "display:block;text-align:left;box-shadow:0px 0px 60px;" : "display:block;text-align:left;";
         
            // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
            var swfVersionStr = "18.0.0";
            // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
            var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
            var flashvars = (isFacebook()) ? {} : kongregateAPI.flashVarsObject();
            var params = {};
            params.quality = "high";
            params.bgcolor = "#000000";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            params.allowFullScreenInteractive = "true";
            params.wmode = "direct";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "FSPreloader";
            attributes.name = "FSPreloader";
            attributes.align = "middle";
   attributes.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "FSPreloader.swf" + v, "flashContent",  
                "800", "600", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
            // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
            swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", cssStyle);
        </script>
        
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">#flashContent {box-shadow:0px 0px 60px black} </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body id="body">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.11'
              });

              // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE
            };

            (function(d, s, id){
               var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
               if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
               js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
               js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
             }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));    
  </script>
  
  <center>
   <div style="box-shadow:0px 0px 60px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px; width:800px;">
    <div id="flashContent">
     <p style="background-color:black;">
     <font color="red">
     <b> To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version
     18.0.0 or greater is installed. Make sure to install it by downloading it from <strong><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">here</a></strong>
     (Right click and Select "Open link on new tab" if single click does not work). If after installing doesn't work, make sure to "Activate always" Flash extension on your browser and untick the "Block Dangerous and intrusive Flash Content".
     </b>
     </font>
     </p>
     <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Flash</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Pasting here a link to the solution we found in case anyone has the same issue:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1202849#answer-1073221